# Mongoose remove clear entire array element inside a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a record with

```
{
  "_id": "3536463525325645",
  "name": "james",
  "friends": [
    "jack",
    "john",
    "jeff",
    "michael"
  ]
}
```

I want to clear the entire array so the result would be:

```
{
  "_id": "3536463525325645",
  "name": "james",
  "friends": [
  ]
}
```

I try using $pull but with no avail.
Anyone with any suggestions?

Comment: what was your `$pull` query?

Comment: you could do `friends = new Array()` and then save it. I think that's the best option if you want to just delete everything from the array

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with an [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) statement:

```
Person.update({name:"james"}, { $set: { friends: [] }}, function(err, affected){
    console.log('affected: ', affected);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to use async/await with update this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements including key of the element attributes list.
Here is the example of mongoDB unset operator:

```
db.UM_PREAUTH_CASE.update(
{ 'Id' : 123},
{ $unset: { dataElements: ""} }
)
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
"Id":123,
"dataElements" : [ 
        {
            "createdBy" : "Kishore Babu Diyyana",
            "createdByUserId" : 2020
        },
        {
            "createdBy" : "Diyyana Kishore",
            "createdByUserId" : 2021
        }
    ]
}
```